# Why can I not increase my Java heap space?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am working on a project in which execution at some size of data requires additional heap space, The actual problem is that I tried multiple approaches to solve but all in vain.

At first, I started by editing my launch.json file since I am using VSCode, tried adding the Xmx parameter to the vmArgs.
nothing, I added a portion of code to my Main class which goes as follows:

```
 System.out.println("====================================================================");
 System.out.println("JVM arguments:");
 RuntimeMXBean runtimeMxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
 List<String> jvmArgs = runtimeMxBean.getInputArguments();
 for (String arg : jvmArgs) {
 System.out.println(arg);
 }

 // Print actual heap size used by the JVM
 System.out.println("Max Memory: " + (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / (1024 * 1024)) + " MB");
 // Your application code goes here
 System.out.println("====================================================================");

 long maxMemory = rutime.maxMemory();
 System.out.println("Max Memory: " + maxMemory / (1024 * 1024) + " MB");
```

This code displays jvm Arguments and of course actual max memory to be used by JAVA on my system.
It is initially set at 1896 MB. Output:

```
====================================================================
JVM arguments:
-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
Max Memory: 1896 MB
====================================================================
Max Memory: 1896 MB
```

I tried adding the JAVA-OPTS variable to the system. Nothing changed after re-executing.

```
./././.>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe" -Xmx2G -cp <path_to_my_main_class> Main
```

tried executing from terminal and specifying the Xmx value, and my `Main` class weren't recognized, even though I multiple-checked syntax, path and class name, same thing on cmd and vscode terminal (windows 11).
And still when I execute under VScode the main class runs correctly before returning the `java.lang.outOfMemoryerror`.

also I noticed that I had two different version of java on my pc by executing the command:

```
>where java
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
```

while VSCode execution starts this way:

```
PS D:\Studies\M1\S2\TPs\méth\Projet Méta>  d:; cd 'd:\Studies\M1\S2\TPs\méth\Projet Méta'; & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '-cp' 'C:\Users\wahee\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\bdc4f5af61bc4e992a3808de6bdc92e9\redhat.java\jdt_ws\Projet Méta_de071d7c\bin' 'Main'
```

seems to specify another java instance. that I added to path system variable, and still nothing (made sure to constantly restart my PC)

I browsed stack overflow, google, and pushed chatGPT to his limits to a point it's just keeps apologizing and repeating steps over and over again...

I also accessed the control panel to add `-Xmx` and `-Xms` arguments within a java interface using a specific dialogue box with no change.

I am running on a x64 architecture.  What Am I missing in all this? Or should I try something else?

Comment: did you restart your shell after changing the system environment variables? (you need to) and what do you mean by "different instance"? the full path the java.exe is the same.

Comment: yes I restarted my, shell , at some point even my computer.
 By different java intances I mean java.exe files in my machines, two appeared under the folder program Files and program Files (x86) when I executed the command where java in my shell to locate java...

But VSCode starts running by specifying a third path that didn't appear before ... 
'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe'

Do I have to increase heap space to the last one only ? how then ? Or I'm I missing to understand something ?